# UITextField without get property swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have custom control which contains textField. Sample code looks like this:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyTextField: UIView {
  private var _text: String?
  private var textField: UITextField?

@IBInspectable var text: String? {
    get {
        return _text
    } set (newValue) {
        guard let txt = newValue else { return }
        self._text = txt
        //updateView()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    updateView()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    updateView()
}

func updateView() {
    textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 97, height: 30))
    self.addSubview(textField!)
    textField!.text = self._text
}}
```

When I create an outlet to my custom control in code I can `set` text property, but I can't `get` it. What am I doing wrong ? I'm new in this so I don't understand...

**EDIT:**

1. Add MyTextField to Main.storyboard and standard textField
2. Create an outlets ​`@IBOutlet var myTextField: MyTextField!` and

   standardTextField
3. Set Text property of my control in Object Inspector 
   [image]
4. My control on storyboard updates correctly and "test text" is visible
5. Add a button and create an action outlet

   **case 1: works fine**

   @IBAction func click(_ sender: UIButton) {
         myTextField.text = standardTextField.text 
      }

   **case 2: doesn't work**

   @IBAction func click(_ sender: UIButton) {
   standardTextField.text = myTextField.text 
   }

   After case 2, in standardTextField is only value which i set from object inspector. If i change value of myTextField.text, standardTextField still shows a orginal value from object inspector

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to `get` it? Calling `myTextField.text` won't compile?

Comment: @NRitH please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your setup in Xcode. Case 2 does work — the standardTextField displays MyTextField's text when the button is clicked.

Note: in MyTextField I assumed that you want to create `textField` once, instead of recreating it each time the text updates. Case 2 was working without this change, though.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myTextField: MyTextField!
    @IBOutlet var standardTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func click(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // myTextField.text = standardTextField.text // Case 1 works
        standardTextField.text = myTextField.text // Case 2 works
    }
}
```

MyTextField control:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyTextField: UIView {
    private var _text: String?
    private var textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 97, height: 30))

    @IBInspectable var text: String? {
        get {
            return _text
        } set (newValue) {
            guard let txt = newValue else { return }
            self._text = txt
            updateView()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addSubview(textField)
        updateView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.addSubview(textField)
        updateView()
    }

    func updateView() {
        textField.text = self._text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still I don't know what am I doing wrong. When I changed with your suggestions "create textField once" I have interface builder error: "Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): The agent threw an exception"

Comment: @emerog Check the error in console.app and read the log, it might help. The error may have different causes. Try to implement all inits like initFromCoder etc. and make sure that updateView() is called in each. Check for conflicts in constraints. If you reference constraints in code, check if none of them are nil. Be careful with naming a class MyTextField if it doesn't actually inherit from UITextfield. That might be a design code smell. This is a View that wraps around a UITextfield. You might be often misled later by the name of this class and have problems overriding some properties.

Comment: @TomaszNazarenko Thanks for suggestions Tomasz. I will check all of this. But... I rollback to previous version and this error still exists.. I hate computers :D

Comment: I've just updated the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` function. It needed the line `self.addSubview(textField)`. Does that help?

Comment: @dxb Unfortunately not. I think problem is in other setups in my custom class, but I don’t know why it appear now.

Comment: I dislike this error. This is an IB agent crash and it is very obscure. Remember to clean the project and to clean build folder (delete derived data). My guess is that this won`t help you and you will have to rollback even further ;-) In my case I had to do just that. However, if you manage to solve it, let me know how :) I might learn something new.

Comment: @TomaszNazarenko thanks, i will try to find a solution ;) ps pozdrowienia dla Wrocławia;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for not working getter is change text property 
**from**:

```
@IBInspectable var text: String? {
    get {
        return _text
    } set (newValue) {
        guard let txt = newValue else { return }
        self._text = txt
        updateView()
    }
}
```

**to**

```
@IBInspectable var text: String? {
    get {
        return textField!.text
    } set (newValue) {
        guard let txt = newValue else { return }
        self._text = txt
        updateView()
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this is correct... 
Does it make any sense ?